# How to define a type in TypeScript which can have any properties except the specific one?

Tags: typescript

When writing an interface to a dict like store, I'd like to distinguish data model and item in store, which is id & model. I want to add constrain that model itself does not used field `id` in their interface, but I don't know how to do that.

```
type Item<T> = T & {id: string} 
// T is type of model
// Item<T> is type of objects in the store, use id as primary key
```

following function is simplified version, which is used to add new item in store

```
function add<T>(model: Item<T>): T {
    const id = uuid();
    const result = {...model, id};
    store.push(result);
    return result;
}
```

it's better to add some constrain on `T` that `T` does not have `id` property, otherwise `T` would be same as `Item<T>`, meanwhile the `id` in `Item<T>` is not the same one in `T`, which would lead to bugs.

As a summary, I need some type like this

```
type Item<T extends "The type which allow any type without property id: string"> = T & {id : string}
```

I've tried the following approaches:

```
type T0 = Exclude<any, {id: string}>; // any
type T1 = Exclude<{}, {id: string}>; // {}
type SafeModel<T extends Exclude<T, {id: string}>>; //circular constrain
```

None of them works.

I want some thing like

```
type Model // define like this 
const v0: Model = {name: 'someName'} // ok
const v2: Model = {value: 123, id: 'someId'} //ok
const v1: Model = {name: 'someName', id: 'someId'} //error
```

or the way to bypass circular constrain to define type, which allows to define

```
type Model<T> = T extends { id: string } ? never: T;
type Item<T extends Model<T>> = T & { id: string }
```

Comment: The version you have look about like what I would have done. Just an esthetic preference, I would use a string literal type with a message (is `'model must not have id' `) instead of `never` that way the compiler will give you a hint as to what is not ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript negative type check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328700/typescript-negative-type-check)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `never` type to tell TypeScript `id` should not be there:

```
interface Unidentifiable extends Object {
    id?: never;
}
```

It will allow only objects without a property called `id` and the ones with `id` set to `undefined`.

Use it as a constraint on your parameter type:

```
type Item<T extends Unidentifiable> = T & { id: string };
```

Usage:

```
interface Foo {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

interface Bar {
    profession: string;
    id: string;
}

type T1 = Item<Foo> // OK
type T2 = Item<Bar> // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript mostly uses a Structured Typing strategy (as opposed to Nominal). It is easier to express what a structure should have rather than not have.

Here is a generic type to accomplish something like this:

```
type XorExtend<T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof A
    ? A[K] extends T[K]
        ? never
        : T[K]
    : T[K]
}, A extends object,> = T & A

type a = XorExtend<{ id: string }, { a: 1 }> // okay
type b = XorExtend<{ id: string }, { id: 'asdf' }> // not okay!
type c = XorExtend<{ id: string }, { id: 1 }> // okay
```

playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20XorExtend%3CT%20extends%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20K%20extends%20keyof%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20A%5BK%5D%20extends%20T%5BK%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%5BK%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%5BK%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20A%20extends%20object%2C%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20a%20%3D%20XorExtend%3C%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%3E%0D%0Atype%20b%20%3D%20XorExtend%3C%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'asdf'%20%7D%3E%0D%0Atype%20c%20%3D%20XorExtend%3C%7B%20id%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%201%20%7D%3E)

Presuming you're using a function somewhere you could leverage something this as well:

```
declare function xorExtend<O, P extends { [K in keyof P]: K extends keyof O
    ? O[K] extends P[K]
        ? never
        : P[K]
    : P[K]
}>(a: O, b: P): P & O


const test = xorExtend( { id: '' }, { b: '' } ) // ok, test: {id: ''} & {b: ''}
const test2 = xorExtend( { id: '' }, { id: 'whatever' } ) // not okay
const test3 = xorExtend( { id: '' }, { id: 4 } ) // okay
```

Link to playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20function%20xorExtend%3CO%2C%20P%20extends%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20P%5D%3A%20K%20extends%20keyof%20O%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20O%5BK%5D%20extends%20P%5BK%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20P%5BK%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20P%5BK%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3E(a%3A%20O%2C%20b%3A%20P)%3A%20P%20%26%20O%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20xorExtend(%7B%20id%3A%20''%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20''%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20ok%2C%20test%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20''%7D%20%26%20%7Bb%3A%20''%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20xorExtend(%7B%20id%3A%20''%20%7D%2C%7B%20id%3A%20'whatever'%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20not%20okay%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20xorExtend(%7B%20id%3A%20''%20%7D%2C%7B%20id%3A%204%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20okay)

Hope this helps!

Here is my gist for this on github:

https://gist.github.com/babakness/82eba31701195d9b68d4119a5c59fd35