# Typescript - Tuple must contain, or cannot contain a specific named value

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function like so:

```
const fn = <T extends [...any]>() { }
```

I want to constrain the Tuple so the Tuple must contain a specific named element.
This is possible with objects like shown in this answer: [How to define a type in TypeScript which can have any properties except the specific one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909593/how-to-define-a-type-in-typescript-which-can-have-any-properties-except-the-spec)

So, I want something like this:

```
const fn = <T extends [world?: never, ...any]>() { } // This syntax is incorrect because all items have to be named if one is named.

fn<[hello: string, world: string]>() // NOT ALLOWED
fn<[hello: string]>() // ALLOWED
```

And I also want this the other way around:

```
const fn = <T extends [world: string, ...any]>() { } // This syntax is incorrect because all items have to be named if one is named.

fn<[hello: string, world: string]>() // ALLOWED
fn<[hello: string]>() // NOT ALLOWED
```

I know the following is possible without named tuples:

```
type HasString<T> = T extends [string, ...unknown[]] ? T : never;

type T0 = HasString<[string, object, number]> //T0 = [string, object, number]
type T1 = HasString<[object, number]> //T1 = never
```

So, I want something like this, but with named Tuples.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Tuple names are just for documentation. They don't count toward type compatibility and are not really accessible from within the type system. So you can't do what you are asking

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Hmmmmm okay. So then I can only do something like this: `extends [...(string | number)[], object]`