# Issue with generic properties when type mapping

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a library which exports a utility type similar to the following:

```js
type Action<Model extends object> = (data: State<Model>) => State<Model>;
```

This utility type allows you to declare a function that will perform as an "action". It receives a generic argument being the `Model` that the action will operate against.

The `data` argument of the "action" is then typed with another utility type that I export;

```js
type State<Model extends object> = Omit<Model, KeysOfType<Model, Action<any>>>;
```

The `State` utility type basically takes the incoming `Model` generic and then creates a new type where all the properties that are of type `Action` have been removed.

For e.g. here is a basic user land implementation of the above;

```js
interface MyModel {
  counter: number;
  increment: Action<Model>;
}

const myModel = {
  counter: 0,
  increment: (data) => {
    data.counter; // Exists and typed as `number`
    data.increment; // Does not exist, as stripped off by State utility 
    return data;
  }
}
```

The above is working very well.

However, there is a case that I am struggling with, specifically when a generic model definition is defined, along with a factory function to produce instances of the generic model.

For example;

```js
interface MyModel<T> {
  value: T; //  a generic property
  doSomething: Action<MyModel<T>>;
}

function modelFactory<T>(value: T): MyModel<T> {
  return {
    value,
    doSomething: data => {
      data.value; // Does not exist 
      data.doSomething; // Does not exist 
      return data;
    }
  };
}
```

In the example above I expect the `data` argument to be typed where the `doSomething` action has been removed, and the generic `value` property still exists.  This however is not the case - the `value` property has also been removed by our `State` utility.

I believe the cause for this is that `T` is generic without any type restrictions/narrowing being applied to it, and therefore the type system decides that it intersects with an `Action` type and subsequently removes it from the `data` argument type.

Is there a way to get around this restriction? I have done some research and was hoping there would be some mechanism in which I could state that `T` is any *except* for an `Action`. i.e. a negative type restriction.

Imagine:

```js
function modelFactory<T extends any except Action<any>>(value: T): UserDefinedModel<T> {
```

But that feature doesn't exist for TypeScript.

Does anyone know of a way I could get this to work as I expect it to?

---

To aid debugging here is a full code snippet:

```js
// Returns the keys of an object that match the given type(s)
type KeysOfType<A extends object, B> = {
  [K in keyof A]-?: A[K] extends B ? K : never
}[keyof A];

// Filters out an object, removing any key/values that are of Action<any> type
type State<Model extends object> = Omit<Model, KeysOfType<Model, Action<any>>>;

// My utility function.
type Action<Model extends object> = (data: State<Model>) => State<Model>;

interface MyModel<T> {
  value: T; //  a generic property
  doSomething: Action<MyModel<T>>;
}

function modelFactory<T>(value: T): MyModel<T> {
  return {
    value,
    doSomething: data => {
      data.value; // Does not exist 
      data.doSomething; // Does not exist 
      return data;
    }
  };
}
```

You can play with this code example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-star-m4sdb?fontsize=14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. Typescript can't generally do much with regard to generic type parameters in conditional types. It just defers any evaluation of `extends` if it finds that the evaluation involves a type parameter.

An exception applies if we can get typescript to use a special kind of type relation, namely, an **equality relation** (not an extends relation). An equality relation is simple to understand for the compiler, so there is no need to defer the conditional type evaluation. Generic constraints are one of the few places in the compiler where type equality is used. Let's look at an example:

```
function m<T, K>() {
  type Bad = T extends T ? "YES" : "NO" // unresolvable in ts, still T extends T ? "YES" : "NO"

  // Generic type constrains are compared using type equality, so this can be resolved inside the function 
  type Good = (<U extends T>() => U) extends (<U extends T>() => U) ? "YES" : "NO" // "YES"

  // If the types are not equal it is still un-resolvable, as K may still be the same as T
  type Meh = (<U extends T>()=> U) extends (<U extends K>()=> U) ? "YES": "NO" 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwDwBUA0iDSA+ACgEpEBvAKEUSgE8AHAU0QCEBDAE0QF5F1EGAHlAZh2AZ16IA-IgBEATQCiAZVmIAXHIByAeTUB6fYnAAnBmLgAbAG6sARpaYwkUMdjGxLlyYOGiJfDIKKmqasrqy5JSIhrwAFkwA5iIMJjAQ1PRMEAgeJqzOEqxmiDl0xQycIGLOiZmM-CAAjqyWMLSIFtRxMBIQrEh2TGYWNpWIhTDsTFAJiKCQsAiI0bQNAOJwcJw8BKgAqvxCIuK8hCRceIj7JL4nEnuHd-5nxNxXN9JySqoa2noxIzBVRRKixACSwG6MyyRRKYDgUH4TRArQmSN6nU83lM5istgcDGwrAkOBQrBoWJgXkQQ2hnVYyCYJN4qyyiE22wATNxEI8jn5Tuhzpdrrdji9+c9TvhiKLPkEfrIwhEVgBfIA)

We can take advantage of this behavior to identify specific types. Now, this will be an exact type match, not an extends match, and exact type matches are not always suitable. However, since `Action` is just a function signature, exact type matches might work well enough.

Lets see if we can extract types that match a simpler function signature such as `(v: T) => void`:

```
interface Model<T> {
  value: T,
  other: string
  action: (v: T) => void
}

type Identical<T, TTest, TTrue, TFalse> =
  ((<U extends T>(o: U) => void) extends (<U extends TTest>(o: U) => void) ? TTrue : TFalse);

function m<T>() {
  type M = Model<T>
  type KeysOfIdenticalType = {
    [K in keyof M]: Identical<M[K], (v: T) => void, never, K>
  }
  // Resolved to
  // type KeysOfIdenticalType = {
  //     value: Identical<T, (v: T) => void, never, "value">;
  //     other: "other";
  //     action: never;
  // }

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2AeAFQD5kBvAKGWQDc4cBXCALmQIBpLl0wALaFgM5gooAOadEYYOhAsAFNRYEAlMgC8JaumCZyAX3LkwATwAOKAJLZwwBHUJtWBCEMcECURm4BidARBI1Tjk5PABVZAgAD0gQTAFWIjl0FjDVDRptTFVo2PjkUIjciDiE9xcwJJTkNPVNLNUAfidPFCVfHH9lAG5DGHoQBCkZZABbQiTVCioTczR1NCxcCc5ZlABpCGMBAHkYKxKpOxwCMxQ1Mk4qAG115FBkAGst9Bg0AF0WA5tjvFRb96OBRKdL1HSOEAQajQRzrIicAxUAD0SOQACUXOgcNDMMgwOhOCi8WdkJttntvkc6Kc5hdpsgiVQqLQGMxkJTbPZ2AVFKxQZlwchIdCoI4AEQsxhioi9ZGoplcXj8ZBi7h8KBi2UM+VMyTSWRCqHQLVEgz6IA)

The above type `KeysOfIdenticalType` is close to what we need for filtering. For `other`, the property name is preserved. For the `action`, the property name is erased. There is just one pesky issue around `value`. Since `value` is of type `T`, is is not trivially resolvable that `T`, and `(v: T) => void` are not identical (and in fact they may not be).

We can still determine that `value` is identical to `T`: for properties of type `T`, intersect this check for `(v: T) => void` with `never`. Any intersection with `never` is trivially resolvable to `never`. We can then add back properties of type `T` using another identity check:

```
interface Model<T> {
  value: T,
  other: string
  action: (v: T) => void
}

type Identical<T, TTest, TTrue, TFalse> =
  ((<U extends T>(o: U) => void) extends (<U extends TTest>(o: U) => void) ? TTrue : TFalse);

function m<T>() {
  type M = Model<T>
  type KeysOfIdenticalType = {
    [K in keyof M]:
      (Identical<M[K], (v: T) => void, never, K> & Identical<M[K], T, never, K>) // Identical<M[K], T, never, K> will be never is the type is T and this whole line will evaluate to never
      | Identical<M[K], T, K, never> // add back any properties of type T
  }
  // Resolved to
  // type KeysOfIdenticalType = {
  //     value: "value";
  //     other: "other";
  //     action: never;
  // }

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Gh0RgsABE6sYRd6YdJee4fCgxZr0HLCarP0k0lkuvpFZzpIM+iAA)

The final solution looks something like this:

```
// Filters out an object, removing any key/values that are of Action<any> type
type State<Model extends object, G = unknown> = Pick<Model, {
    [P in keyof Model]:
      (Identical<Model[P], Action<Model, G>, never, P> & Identical<Model[P], G, never, P>)
    | Identical<Model[P], G, P, never>
  }[keyof Model]>;

// My utility function.
type Action<Model extends object, G = unknown> = (data: State<Model, G>) => State<Model, G>;


type Identical<T, TTest, TTrue, TFalse> =
  ((<U extends T>(o: U) => void) extends (<U extends TTest>(o: U) => void) ? TTrue : TFalse);

interface MyModel<T> {
  value: T; //  a generic property
  str: string;
  doSomething: Action<MyModel<T>, T>;
  method() : void
}


function modelFactory<T>(value: T): MyModel<T> {
  return {
    value,
    str: "",
    method() {

    },
    doSomething: data => {
      data.value; // ok
      data.str //ok
      data.method() // ok 
      data.doSomething; // Does not exist 
      return data;
    }
  };
}

/// Still works for simple types
interface MyModelSimple {
  value: string; 
  str: string;
  doSomething: Action<MyModelSimple>;
}


function modelFactory2(value: string): MyModelSimple {
  return {
    value,
    str: "",
    doSomething: data => {
      data.value; // Ok
      data.str
      data.doSomething; // Does not exist 
      return data;
    }
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=2#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-iuEhruyeT-p8YEtIOw4QROA50t636FLSNjIre8BFhCaA8P+BRYTgyLdsRqHYRBUHFmAhGgJRpHIohI5jhIvb4WAAAiaBiKAsTYJ4kDtqAJaALI7lG0LAH4EKR-YFLuimgru4IQtYMBuHEhEoPCF4AZAdCGNAGICsgcbdEgSYppCgKWIZxkYq+uFdh2nGMQUgEAW5bD9qxyFsJOWIOLOtT2UZJlLqp+6IqMBAnq4Z6wBenAAEytC53k9mwD62XO4WOdmzTSbJRUtLh8GFF5IGVSRQ5seOgVUTg6FMXSOG-nhdGgAA8kRLQke1FEDc1LH1QFfbdbx-GCbiInYBJUnvp+zUKaASnrSpQA)

**NOTES:** The limitation here is that this only works with one type parameter (although it can possibly be adapted to more). Also, the API is a bit confusing for any consumers, so this might not be the best solution. There may be issues that I have not identified yet. If you find any, let me know

Comment: I feel like Gandalf the White just revealed himself.  TBH I was ready to write this off as a compiler limitation. So stoked to try this out. Thank you! 

Comment: @ctrlplusb  LOL, that comment made my day 

Comment: I meant to apply the bounty to this answer but I have severe lack of sleep baby brain going on and misclicked. My apologies! This is a fantastically insightful answer. Albeit quite complex in nature.  Thank you so much for taking the time to answer it.

Comment: @ctrlplusb :( Oh well .. win some lose some :)

Comment: Not working in Typescript 5.1.6

Answer (score 2):

> It would be great if I could express that T is not of type Action. Sort of an inverse of extends

Exactly like you said, the problem is we don't have negative constraint yet. I also hope they can land such feature soon. While waiting, I propose a workaround like this:

```js
type KeysOfNonType<A extends object, B> = {
  [K in keyof A]-?: A[K] extends B ? never : K
}[keyof A];

// CHANGE: use `Pick` instead of `Omit` here.
type State<Model extends object> = Pick<Model, KeysOfNonType<Model, Action<any>>>;

type Action<Model extends object> = (data: State<Model>) => State<Model>;

interface MyModel<T> {
  value: T;
  doSomething: Action<MyModel<T>>;
}

function modelFactory<T>(value: T): MyModel<T> {
  return {
    value,
    doSomething: data => {
      data.value; // Now it does exist 
      data.doSomething; // Does not exist 
      return data;
    }
  } as MyModel<any>; // <-- Magic!
                     // since `T` has yet to be known
                     // it literally can be anything
}
```

Comment: Not ideal, but great to know of a semi workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

`count` and `value` will always make the compiler unhappy. To fix it you might try something like this:

```
{
  value,
  count: 1,
  transform: (data: Partial<Thing<T>>) => {
   ...
  }
}
```

Since `Partial` utility type is being used, you will be ok in the case `transform` method is not present.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yt2em4)

Comment: "count and value will always make the compiler unhappy" - I would appreciate some insight into the why here. xx

Answer (score 1):

Generally I read that twice and don't fully understand what you want to achieve. From my understanding you want to omit `transform` from the type which is given to exactly `transform`. Achieving that is simple, we need to use [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk):

```
interface Thing<T> {
  value: T; 
  count: number;
  transform: (data: Omit<Thing<T>, 'transform'>) => void; // here the argument type is Thing without transform
}

//  the factory function accepting the generic
function makeThing<T>(value: T): Thing<T> {
  return {
    value,
    count: 1,
      transform: data => {
        data.count; // exist
        data.value; // exist
    },
  };
}
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted because of quite a complexity you have given in the additional utility types. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I wish. But this is a utility type I am exporting for 3rd party consumption. I don't know the shape/properties of their objects. I just know I need to strip off all function properties and utilise the result against the transform func data argument.

Comment: I've updated my issue description in the hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: The main issue is that T can be also Action type as it is not defined to exclude it. Hope will find some solution. But I am in the place where count is ok but T is still omitted because it's intersection with Action

Comment: It would be great if I could express that T is not of type Action. Sort of an inverse of extends.

Comment: Relative discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328700/typescript-negative-type-check